# How to process dependencies between tasks considering multiple constraints?

Tags: java, dependencies, graph-theory, jung, constraint-programming

I'm working on a Java program that take an input file containing a bunch of depencencies between tasks like this :

```
 C --> D 
 A --> B
 A --> D
 F --> G
 B --> C
 E --> F
```

"C --> D" means that task D can only start after C is finished but doesn't necessarily mean that D comes right after C. Tasks can also run in parallel if they are independent from each others (A & E for instance).

The program should process all those depencencies and generate an output dependency list considering the following constraints :

- Find all the sources (A & E in this case) and order the dependencies begining from the sources :

> ```
> A --> B
> A --> D
> B --> C
> C --> D
> E --> F
> F --> G
> ```

- Remove all the useless dependencies (in this case : A --> D)
- At the end, add a "Start" task as a root for all the dependecies by adding dependencies between "Start" and the sources. The generated output list should look like this :

> ```
> Start --> A
> Start --> E
> A --> B
> B --> C
> C --> D
> E --> F
> F --> G
> ```

Then i've got to display a rooted tree graph from the dependency list above using a specialised library like "Jung".

Any ideas on how to process all those contraints ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why a rooted tree?  There are cases where the answer won't be a tree.

Comment: smells like homework to me.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what OP has tried; but I guess we're not allowed to ask that any more.

Comment: @DavidWallace : I've got to display a tree with "Start" as a root in all cases. It's in the specs.

Comment: @duffymo : does it prevent me from asking questions ?? (i'm not a student though)

Comment: Why is A --> D useless? Why isn't C --> D the useless one? How can you make the code tell the difference? Answer that and I think you will begin to understand how to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to use JaCoP which is a constraint logic programming Library but still didn't manage which constraints to use for this problem.

Comment: Whether it's in the spec or not, it might not be a tree.  You might have A->B A->C B->D C->D which means you've got a loop, not a tree.

Comment: @DavidWallace, you are right. Detecting cycles is one of the constraints. But i already know how to do this.

Comment: Whether you know how to do it or not, it still means that what you're asking for makes no sense.  I think you should try to reformulate the question, so that it's actually answerable; because if you can't express what you need in English, none of us are going to be able to express it in Java.

Comment: @David Wallace, Sorry, i tought my question was clear, could you pls tell me what you don't understand ?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon : I already tought about it a lot of time but i still can't find out exactely how to do it. Any ideas would be welcomed :)

Comment: There isn't anything here that I don't understand.  It's just that you're asking for something that isn't a tree to magically become a tree.  Unless you give more detail about how you want the "loop" case to be handled, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @David Wallace, for the loop detection, i use Jgrapht, a free Java graph library : http://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/CycleDetector.html

Comment: CP libraries (JaCoP, OptaPlanner, etc) are probably overkill: I don't think it's NP-complete (it's not [Job Shop Scheduling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c)). Some straightforward code that transforms the input tree into the output tree should work and should be more efficient.

Comment: @Geoffrey De Sme, Thank you very much for your answer. I tried to use OptaPlanner but it looked indeed too complicated for my problem. Now i'm stuck with JaCop trying to find a way to resolve those constraints. But, as you said, some straightforward code could be better and easier for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the sources is trivial; just ask each vertex whether it has any incoming edges.

For the rest, basically you want to extract a spanning tree from the graph; there are several algorithms out there for doing this.

Comment: Your answer looks interesting but could please give more details on how to extract those spanning trees?

Comment: Are you asking for pointers to algorithms, or to implementations?  JUNG has one (minimum weight) spanning tree algorithm implementation, whose use in a layout is demonstrated in one of the demos.

Answer (score 0):

Most of it will be logic, so if a letter like A doesnt appear in the second row then it is one of the starting letters then find the staring letter (in this case A) from the first row and the letter it goes to in the second row and so on until you get to a letter like D which doesnt appear in the first row and you will have one of the chains. Then repeat this for all the starting letters as stated above.